# Regex not returning expected match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace everything inside brackets using a regex, but I seem to be getting an unexpected match.

Here's the text I'm trying to match:

```
Foo (bar)
```

Here's the regex:

```
/(?=\().*(?=\))/
```

I'm expecting it to return everything between the brackets: ie the `.*` or `bar`. However it returns the first bracket with the text: `(bar`.

That shouldn't be happening, right? Since the first bracket is in a positive lookahead `(?=...)`...

Please tell me where I'm going wrong...

Comment: I think you need to change your first instance of `(?=\()` to `(?<=\()` to make it a look behind and instead of lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to brittenb I had to change my lookahead into a lookbehind.

So my Regex became

```
/(?<=\().*(?=\))/
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't allow lookbehinds. When I try that solution in console I get `Invalid regular expression`.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

`/\([^\)]+\)/`

From the string `Foo (bar)` this regex will return the text `(bar)`

Breakdown:

```
/                 #delimiter
    \(            #begins with a open-parenthesis
        [^\)]+    #all content that is not a close-parenthesis
            \)    #ends with a close-parenthesis
                / #end delimiter
```